# How to conditionally execute a JavaScript feature based on the presence of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JavaScript code that includes a feature that relies on 2 HTML elements to function properly. However, there are scenarios where these elements may not be present in the HTML file, depending on the context or use case.

I would like to modify my JavaScript code to conditionally execute the feature based on the presence of the required HTML elements. If the elements are not present, I want to skip the feature to prevent errors and improve the efficiency of the program.

Here is what I came up with:

```js
const elementA = document.getElementById("element-a");
const elementB = document.getElementById("element-b");

function executeFeature() {
  // Check if required HTML elements are present

  if (!elementA || !elementB) {
    return; // Skip feature execution if elements are not present
  }

  // Rest of the feature code...
}
executeFeature();
```

However I am confused if the **above code snippet really checks in the HTML that elements are present, or if it just checks that elements are declared in the JS file.**

```js
const elementA = document.getElementById("element-a");
const elementB = document.getElementById("element-b");
```

The whole point of this question is to improve the code performance so that the code is not executed where it is not required.
Thanks!

Comment: `.getElementById()` is a reference to the DOM, if that's what you're asking. The variables will be `null` if the elements are not found.

Comment: Yes I was asking that only. "The variables will be `null` if the elements are not found." That means my code snippet does the required job right? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll()` to check the both elements:

```js
function executeFeature() {

  if (document.querySelectorAll('#element-a,#element-b').length !== 2) {
    console.log('skip feature');
    return; // Skip feature execution if elements are not present
  }

  console.log('execute feature');
}

executeFeature();

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="element-a"></div>');

executeFeature();

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="element-b"></div>');

executeFeature();
```

Comment: Thanks! How is this different from my code snippet? Just curious.

Comment: @wthrajat seems it's more compact and maybe more efficient because you do the check in only 1 function call. btw if you like my answer, don't forget to accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up). that way i'll be motivated to help you in the future. that's how stackoverflow works, thanks!